# Proper way to speedup a specific sqlite query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am working on a simulation.

In this simulation the agents moves and the movement, with coordinates and time step, is recorded in a sqlite database.

When the simulation is completed, I need to display the position of the agents at a certain time. For this I use a query like

```
SELECT x,y,z,t from movement where t <= ?1 and id = ?2;
```

and I take only the record with `max(t)`. This works fine but it's very slow.

I need to speedup it, and I thought I could change the structure of the database. But I cannot insert a record of the position for each agent, because the db will grow too much.

Same for adding a record of the "last valid position" of the agents at each time step.

So, what are my other options?

Thanks

UPDATE:
For the matter of the problem, the `Movements` table has just a bunch of fields for the position (x,y INTEGERS) time (t INTEGER) and id of the agent (Integer). 
Number of records: timesteps is up to 50.000, agents can be up to 10.000 and movement can happen as frequent as 1/10 time steps. So in a big simulation we could have around 5.000 movements for 10.000 agents = 5M records for movements.

Comment: Things like the amount of records, types of columns, indices and general DB design can make a huge difference. You might get more constructive answers by providing that information as the query itself is pretty straight forward. Also define slow, some people say 3 seconds is slow, some people say 30 seconds is slow.

Comment: Perhaps an index on (id, t) would be useful. Which I think SQLite might be able to use for `t <= ?1 and id = ?2`. This will need testing.

Comment: Yes, you're certainly right. I need to update the position "in real time", I mean use should change the current time and see the position changing. Actually it takes 5+seconds, and it is not acceptable. 1Second would be acceptable. Indexes: I added indexes for ids and for tstep. Of course I don't think tstep is helping a lot, due to the kind of query I'm performing.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the table like so, with primary key on *id* and *t*:

```
CREATE TABLE `Movement` (
    `ID`    INTEGER,
    `T` INTEGER,
    `X` INTEGER,
    `Y` INTEGER,
    `Z` INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(`ID`,`T`)
);
```

and queried like this:

```
select id,t,x,y,z
from Movement
where id=?2 and t = (select max(t) from Movement where id=?2 and t <= ?1);
```

would that help? There must not be any duplicate *id* / *t* pairs in this case.

Comment: There will be no duplicate id/tstep, no way. I think I can do this test, indeed. I'll be back with some measurement, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Phrase the query like this:

```
select x, y, z, t
from movement
where t <= ?1 and id = ?2
order by t desc
limit 1;
```

You can try an index on `movement(id, t, x, y)` for better performance.